# Automatically generating dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I try to create an infinite dropdown list. With this I mean if you click something on the first dropdown list, the second dropdown list will pop up. If you choose something on the second the third one will pop up...

The only difference between the dropdown lists is that only the first one will be required to fill in.

My dropdown list:

```
<select name="dropdown" style="font-size:18pt;height:40px;width:410px;" onclick="myFunction()" required>
<option value="">Choose something</option>
{{range .}} <option value='1'>{{.Name}}</option>
{{end}}
</select>
```

The new coming dropdown lists:

```
<div id="myDIV" style="display:none">    
    <select name="dropdown" style="font-size:18pt;height:40px;width:410px;" onselect="myFunction()">
    <option value="">Choose something</option>
    {{range .}} <option value='1'>{{.Name}}</option>
    {{end}}
    </select>    
</div>
```

The Java Script:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I also searched for another function than onclick, because that's not for the dropdown lists I think, at least it's buggy. I tried some others but than it doesn't do anything

How can I make an automatically infinite generating dropdownlist?

Comment: What framework are you using here? That looks like handlebars but well who knows.

Comment: Firefox (just as an example) has tremendous performance issues with dropdowns including 3k+ items. Do your homework. Not something you want to do. I suggest implementing something with a smart search solution that queries a database and returns perhaps top X results.

Comment: He doesn't want an infinite dropdownlist he wants to add an infinity amount of drop down lists whenever the prepending sibling gets a selection. Still don't know why you would need it to be infinite.

Comment: The options in the dropdown lists are not infinite, only the amount of dropdown lists that can be created are infinite. So i try to create a script that adds a copy of the first <select>...</select>. So people can choose from the list i created in a json file (10 options) and implented by GOlang into the dropdown  list after choosing in the first list a second one will show up, so people can choose more than only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly the following is what you want to do.

```js
var addDropDown = function (e) {
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, addDropDown);
    var clone = e.currentTarget.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('id', "dropdown-" + document.getElementsByTagName("select").length)
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, e.currentTarget.nextSibling);
    clone.addEventListener("change", addDropDown);
}

document.getElementById("dropdown-0").addEventListener("change", addDropDown);
```

```html
<select id="dropdown-0" name="dropdown">
    <option value="">make a selection</option>
    <option value='1'>Option1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think you should still limit the amount of dropdown selections you can create. Just don't apply the event listener `clone.addEventListener("change", addDropDown);` if the max select condition is met.

Comment: edit: starting id to `dropdown-0` so no duplicate ids